# Increase sqlite performance using phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am Phonegap developer.I creating two tables in database.These two tables contains 150 fields.When the page loading I display data from the database(i.e:150 fields). But It consuming more time.

Is any way to show the data less time?. Thanks..

Comment: 150 fields, how many rows?  How are you displaying them?  And how much time is it taking?

Comment: We, really need more info. The only thing you've told us is that you have 150 fields. So, the only solution which I can see based on current info is... have less fields :-)

Comment: I am displaying the data in the form of input fields using jquery.

Comment: tx.executeSql("select * from Crossing_Details where cross_id='"+$("#note_id").val()+"'" ,[],function(tx,results) {});